# Geoserver WPS Plugin not installing (Context initialization failed)

Tags: java, spring, jetty, geoserver

I am attempting to install a WPS plugin for Geoserver to my local Windows machine, and moving `*.jar` files into `WEB-INF/inf` folder causes error that doesn't allow to load Geoserver unless I delete them from there.

The version of Geoserver is 2.20.3 and it's web instance gets loaded with the built-in Jetty web server.

The error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wmtsCapabilitiesProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/GeoServer/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.20.3.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'geoServer' while setting constructor argument;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'geoServer' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/GeoServer/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.20.3.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'catalog' while setting bean property 'catalog'; nested exception is

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localWorkspaceCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/GeoServer/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.20.3.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'advertisedCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'advertisedCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/GeoServer/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.20.3.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'secureCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secureCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/GeoServer/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.20.3.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:314)
```

Comment: Which plugin exactly did you install? Did your server work before the install?

Comment: @IanTurton, its name is `wps-download-plugin`. 
BTW, I just came to a thought - maybe this plugin requires the actual WPS plugin?

Comment: **all** the wps plugins require the main wps plugin